# How to omit wrapper object in JSON when deserialization in Jackson 2 anotation

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson2

I have got a simple Rest with jax-rs

```
@POST
@Path("/user")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
public Response createuser(User user){

    user.name = "pepebotero";
    return  Response.ok(user).build();
```

And the we want to bind to POJO  user

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
}
```

Using the JSON with the object user

```
{
    "User":{
    "name":"geroge",    
    "surname":"jordi"
    }   
}
```

I am lookig for a way to solve as less intrusive as possible to avoid the below errro. I am looking for annotation oriented solution

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "User" (class com.endpoint.User), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "name", "surname"])
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@576599b5; line: 2, column: 10] (through reference chain: com..endpoint.User["User"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the wrapper object using the [@JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html). Basically something like this will do. Note the class name must be same as wrapper object and I think it is case-sensitive too. Try it out.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Acctually with jaxrs annotation I can even chagne the name to avoid case-sensitive  @XmlRootElement(name = "Usser")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlType(name = "Usser")
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)